# HI/P reduction mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, chemistry-in-fiction

I recently answered [a question about Breaking Bad's initial methamphetamine production method](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14079/crystal-meth-in-breaking-bad/14081#14081) (i.e. the reduction of (pseudo)ephedrine). The reaction is as follows:

[image: Ephedrine to methamphetamine using HI/P]
([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Methamphetamine&oldid=588492419#Synthesis))

It is infamously known as the $\ce{HI/P}$ reduction and was (and still is somewhat) a real plague in the United States until cough medicine containing ephedrine came under tightened control. That for an introduction, now the question: what is actually the reaction mechanism of the $\ce{HI/P}$ reduction?

The first step seems like a simple $\ce{S_{N}2}$ substitution of $\ce{I^{-}}$, catalyzed by the protonation of the alcohol group by hydroiodic acid (making it a far better leaving group). But what is the mechanism after that? How is phosphorus involved? Does the $\ce{HI/P}$ reduction have any legal use?

Comment: I guess finding an actual reaction mechanism for this is on the edge of impossible. The first part is probably protonation/ activation and something between $\ce{S_{N}1/S_{N}2}$. The second step is most likely carried out with red phosphorous as an electron source and removal of $\ce{PI3}$. But as for all redox reactions, there are too many possible pathways to determine the mechanism. As for the legal use, there are possibly more effective and selective (and less dangerous) methods to reduce organic compounds.

Comment: Theoretical examinations of these reactions are fine, I think.

Comment: You may find [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.3762/bjoc.8.36) illuminating. The authors propose a stepwise SET mechanism with $\ce{HI}$ being catalytic, recycled by $\ce{P_{red}}$.

Comment: This process is known as the Nagai reduction method. You can read more here: http://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/HI/P_reduction

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [source](http://www.beilstein-journals.org/bjoc/single/articleFullText.htm?publicId=1860-5397-8-36) mentioned in the comments to your question, the first step is indeed nucleophilic substitution of the OH group by $\ce{I-}$, faciliated by protonation of the alcohol. For the second step ($\ce{HI}$ reduction), a radical species was found as an intermediate, and therefore a reduction by single electron transfer (SET) with oxidation of $\ce{I-}$ to $\ce{I2}$ is proposed. Red phosphorus is required for the regeneration of $\ce{HI}$ from $\ce{I2}$. $\ce{P_{red}}$ reacts with $\ce{I2}$ to the phosphorus iodides $\ce{PI3}$ and $\ce{PI5}$, which are subsequently hydrolyzed to $\ce{H3PO3}$/$\ce{H3PO4}$ and $\ce{HI}$, which is reused in further reduction steps. Catalytic amounts of $\ce{HI}$ are therefore sufficient to run the reaction in the presence of phosphorus. However, a too low concentration of $\ce{I-}$ will lead to elimination instead of substitution in the first reaction step.

[image]

([Image source](http://www.beilstein-journals.org/bjoc/single/articleFullText.htm?publicId=1860-5397-8-36))

The SET mechanism of the reduction is not described in detail in the article, so the following is a bit speculative. As a resonance-stabilized radical is involved, homolytic cleavage of the $\ce{C-I}$ bond is one of the first steps, which gives the benzylic radical $\ce{R.}$ and an iodine radical $\ce{I.}$. A single electron is transferred from $\ce{I-}$ to $\ce{R.}$, forming the carbanion $\ce{R-}$ and $\ce{I.}$, which recombines with another iodine radical to $\ce{I2}$. Protonation of $\ce{R-}$ yields the final product.

Comment: I really doubt PI5 exists, PI3 is much more reasonable.

Answer (score 9):

As for the second part of the question, this reaction is actually used commercially in the fine chemicals and specialty chemicals industry. An example that comes to mind is the reduction of 4-hydroxymandelic acid to 4-hydroxyphenylacetic acid. This intermediate is used in one route to the popular beta blocker "atenolol". Of course, as mentioned in the comments, other reactions are often favored when possible. In addition to the issues mentioned, phosphorus and iodine are both relatively expensive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/47157)

Comment: @paracresol Why not? I did ask this. Even though it was not the major part of the question. In addition Jannis Andreska did not answer this, so it is a useful contribution.