# Is there a catalyst that will reduce an alcohol to an alkane?

Tags: catalysis

There are many reduction methods of going from an alcohol to an alkane: http://www.transtutors.com/chemistry-homework-help/hydrocarbons/reduction-of-alcohols.aspx

And there are catalytic methods of adding hydrogen  gas to aldehydes and keystones to convert them into alcohols: http://jmcct.com/products-services/product_p404.html

However, I have not found a catalytic method of converting an alcohol into an alkane using a catalyst and possibly hydrogen. The fewer non-catalytic entities the better.

Comment: What about acid-catalyzed dehydration?

Comment: @Dissenter I would prefer to avoid reagents that are not recoverable because of cost considerations. That is why I asked for catalysts.

Comment: It's an acid-catalyzed reaction so the reagent (sulfuric acid) is preserved. @JoeHobbit.

Comment: What I meant is that you can catalyze the dehydration of the alcohol and form an alkene and then hydrogenate or otherwise reduce to an alkane.

Comment: @Dissenter That sounds terrific.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a method for converting secondary and tertiary alcohols into the corresponding alkane using $\ce{InCl3}$ as a catalyst.  Chlorodiphenylsilane is the only reagent used in addition to the catalyst. The method works in the presence of common functional groups leaving them untouched.

[image]

Since primary alcohols are unreactive, this reaction can be used to selectively reduce secondary and tertiary alcohols in their presence.  An abstract showing a number of examples of the reaction can be found [here](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/abstracts/literature/431.shtm).

Answer (score 8):

This is a very limited situation, but benzylic alcohols can be reduced to the corresponding alkyl group with simple hydrogenolysis conditions, hydrogen gas with Pd/C. This is similar to the cleavage of benzyl ethers, a common protecting group. Looking at it this way, the reaction deprotects water. An example of this reaction that I ran long ago is depicted below.

[image]

Developing a more general method for this transformation is an ongoing field of research, with many methods published. That often means that there isn't one single best method (yet). A 2013 publication from Li and coworkers used an iridium complex with hydrazine as the terminal oxidant. Benzylic, allylic, and notably primary alcohols were successfully reduced, although the benzylic/allylic substrates worked much better. The introduction offers a brief description on the state of the field: [Iridium-Catalyzed Direct Dehydroxylation of Alcohols](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ejoc.201301293/abstract)

Comment: As a side note, even zinc dust can reduce phenols to benzenes.

Answer (score 6):

The following not catalytic and does not use hydrogen but tin hydrides:

1. Convert the alcohol to a xanthate
2. Treat with $\ce{Bu3SnH}$ and AIBN

Yes, it's the [Barton-McCombie](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/P19750001574) reaction.

If you don't mind a bit of photochemistry, use the method described by **Isao Saito** ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00271a057)):

1. Convert the alcohol to a *m*-trifluoromethylbenzoate
2. Photolyze (high pressure $\ce{Hg}$ lamp) in THF/water in the presence of *N*-methylcarbazole as an electron donor

Answer (score 5):

Red P + HI is a very strong reducing agent. It would reduce your alcohol to an alkane, but it might reduce other functional groups present as well. See [earlier question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15586/hi-p-reduction-mechanism) for details.