# Clemmensen reduction of 1,3 diketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

As part of a synthesis I was considering the following reaction:

[image: reaction]

How selective is the [Clemmensen reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clemmensen_reduction)? I know that this reduction favours ketones adjacent to benzene rings but will it also reduce the other ketone, and/or affect any other parts of the molecule. Are there any other methods that would achieve this transformation more effectively.

Comment: Use a weak base/TMSCl to form a 6-cyclic (O-silyl)ketal with the outer carbonyl then use Wolff-Kishner ? Probably not good yield.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *Clemmensen* reduction of a 1,3-diketone probably isn't the best idea. The reduction is likely to proceed via a ketyl radical.

[image]

In the case of a 1,3-diketone, formation of a dihydroxy cyclopropane, which undergoes opening/rearrangement cannot be excluded.

This reaction has for instance been observed for dimedone, where 2,4,4-trimethyl cyclopentanone was formed.

**EDIT 1**

Which other viable procedures exist?

If you insist on using the given starting material, the following **might (!)** work:

1. regioselective (asymmetric) catalytic hydrogenation of the acetophenone-type carbonyl using a 1,2-diamine-substituted *Noyori* catalyst
2. [Barton-McCombie](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16379/is-there-a-catalyst-that-will-reduce-an-alcohol-to-an-alkane/16619#16619) reaction of the resulting alcohol

If you are rather interested in the product, you might want to rethink the strategy:

The intended product is an **arylbutanone**, related to the raspberry ketone. A possible retrosynthesis would be:

[image: Retrosynthesis of an arylbutan-2-one]

If you get your hands on the necessary benzaldehyde, an aldol reaction with acetone, followed by catalytic hydrogenation might give the right product.

**EDIT 2**

5-tert.-butyl-2-hydroxybenzaldehyde is commerically available, but not really cheap.

However, 4-tert.-butylphenol is cheap as dirt. In case you need significant quantities of your final product, you might want to consider the synthesis of the benzaldehyde. The substitution pattern cries for a *Reimer-Tiemann* reaction.

Comment: Are there any suitable alternative methods for this transformation then?

Comment: @bon I've added a possible strategy to my answer.