# Why is Red Phosphorous used in the Nagai Method?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

The most common method of producing Dextromethamphetamine (Crystal Meth) is supposedly the Nagai Method, where Pseudoephedrine, Hydriodic acid and Red Phosphorous are refluxed overnight, producing a mixture of Dextromethamphetamine, water and *Red Phosphorous* which may be reused.

The thing is, I don't quite understand how the Red Phosphorous ends up in the mixture as though it were acting as a catalyst.

The best mechanism I could think up was the following:

Pseudoephedrine + Hydriodic acid --> Iodoephedrine + Water
Iodoephedrine + Hydriodic acid --> Methamphetamine + Iodine

Using no Red Phosphorous at all.

The only use of Red Phosphorous I can see here would be to convert the Iodine back to Hydriodic acid, which would give Phosphoric acid as a byproduct, not Red Phosphorous.

What exactly is the Red Phosphorous supposed to be doing here?

**EDIT:** I notice that [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15586/hi-p-reduction-mechanism) question is very similar to mine, however whilst the answer to that question does address the use of the Red Phosphorous (Phosphoric acid is produced as I had assumed), it unfortunately doesn't explain how it ends up back as Red Phosphorous in the end.

**Disclaimer:** I am merely interested from a theoretical standpoint and have no intention of *making* Dextromethamphetamine. Just saying.

Comment: @Mithoron I may have accidentally clicked on the 'Possible Duplicate' banner's "This answers my question" button... Can that be undone by any chance?

Comment: Your question has entered a reopen queue. If 5 people consider it reopenable, it'll be opened.