# Reduction of alcohol to alkane

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, organic-reduction

I have been looking everywhere for hours now, and can't find anything on a simple lab reduction of an alcohol to an alkane that doesn't involve any "fancy" reagents such as tosylates, metal catalysts etc.

I would have expected that under acidic circumstances, the oxygen donates an electron to the proton from the acid, and a hydride from a general reducing agent such as LAH or NaBH4 then attaches itself to the carbon, pushing out a molecule of water, and alkane.

However, I have found no proof or mention of the existence of such a reaction. If this is is impossible, then why, and what would be the best general purpose way to reduce an OH to a H

Comment: Of course it's impossible. For ex. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15586/hi-p-reduction-mechanism is an option

Comment: If you regard tosylates as fancy reagents then your career in synthetic chemistry is going to be very limited.

Answer (score 2):

May I introduce you to the Barton-McCombie reaction for the reduction of alcohols to alkanes.

[image]

image and further information [here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/barton-mccombie-reaction.shtm)

Comment: Perhaps too "fancy". ;)